# List is not updated after mapping over it

Tags: scala

I want the output of my first code to add 42 in each number from 1 to 100
and in second code I want it to change any lowercase in name to upper case
but the first only prints number from 1 to 100
and second only first letter upper case as it was.

```scala
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
object parallelpro1 extends App{
  val list = (1 to 100).toList
  list.par.map(_ + 42)
  println(list)
  // map
  val lastNames = List("Smith","Jones","Frankenstein","Bach","Jackson","Rodin").par
  lastNames.map(_.toUpperCase())
  println(lastNames)
}
```

Comment: you also need to understand that for light operations (like `_ + 42`) .par list may perform operations slowly, not faster. But for heavy operations it should be faster (see task parallelism and data parallelism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to understand that scala collections like List are immutable, `list.par.map(_ + 42)` does not change the `list` but creates a new one, you need to assign it to a new val, the same applies to `lastNames.map(_.toUpperCase())`.